# Start a detached process on Windows using Golang

Tags: windows, go

I have a Golang code which must run a detached child process.

The Linux version of my implementation using `syscall.ForkExec` like this.

```
syscall.ForkExec(my_program, []string{}, nil)
```

But I can't found Windows implementation. I have found a proposition using `START /B`.

```
cmd := exec.Command("START", "/B", my_program)
cmd.Start()
```

Unfortunately, `START` can't be found and I have no other solution using Golang.

Comment: Is `START` a program? Is it in your path? is it missing the `.exe` extension? What are the exact arguments used by the working `ForkExec`, (though the Linux implementation should also be using the `os/exec` package, and not `syscall` directly)

Comment: You should probably look at `StartProcess` https://golang.org/pkg/os/#StartProcess

Comment: @Ravi: `os/exec` should be preferred, From the docs: _It wraps os.StartProcess to make it easier to remap stdin and stdout, connect I/O with pipes, and do other adjustments._

Comment: `START` is a program available in command line but I can't found it into `C:\Windows\System32`.

For Linux I uses `syscall` which detach the child process instead of `os/exec`.

Comment: @JimB `start` is an (internal) command of the Windows command line interpreter (`cmd.exe`). [Details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb491005(v=technet.10)).

Comment: Agreed @JimB. Here he mentions that he wanted to start a detached process, so I got an impression that he doesn't need any control.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`start` is not a standalone application, it's an (internal) command of the Windows command line interpreter (`cmd.exe`) (details: [Command line reference / Start](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb491005(v=technet.10))), so you need a "shell" to run the `start` command.

Use `cmd.exe` with the `/C` parameter, and pass `start` and your application to run.

Like in this example:

```
s := []string{"cmd.exe", "/C", "start", `c:\path\to\your\app\myapp.exe`}

cmd := exec.Command(s[0], s[1:]...)
if err := cmd.Run(); err != nil {
    log.Println("Error:", err)
}
```

Or without the command slice:

```
cmd := exec.Command("cmd.exe", "/C", "start", `c:\path\to\your\app\myapp.exe`)
if err := cmd.Run(); err != nil {
    log.Println("Error:", err)
}
```

You may also pass the `/b` param to `start` like this if you don't want a terminal window for the launched application:

```
cmd := exec.Command("cmd.exe", "/C", "start", "/b", `c:\path\to\your\app\myapp.exe`)
if err := cmd.Run(); err != nil {
    log.Println("Error:", err)
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! Exactly the solution for my problem.

Comment: As a clarification, and because it's not mentioned in the answer; the child process remains even if the parent program exit with a non-zero code. (which os.exec does not provides under windows)

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear to me what you mean by detached. If you mean in the sense, "don't wait for program to finish", you don't need a shell for that:

```
package main
import "os/exec"

func main() {
   exec.Command("firefox", "google.com/search?q=golang").Start()
}
```

https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec#Cmd.Start